# Expected an identifier. for GroupModel.fromDocumentSnapshot flutter

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-dependencies

It's say Expected an identifier. In the `late final groupId2 = GroupModel.fromDocumentSnapshot(doc: );`

I don't what to put inside it. I am New to to flutter

The Screen:

```
late final groupId2 = GroupModel.fromDocumentSnapshot(doc: //Expected an identifier HERE);
```

This is the groupModel:

```
factory GroupModel.fromDocumentSnapshot({required DocumentSnapshot doc}) {
    return GroupModel(
      id: doc.id,
      name: (doc.data() as Map<String, dynamic>)["name"],
      leader: (doc.data() as Map<String, dynamic>)["leader"],
      members: List<String>.from((doc.data() as Map<String, dynamic>)["members"]),
      groupCreate: (doc.data() as Map<String, dynamic>)["groupCreate"],
    );
  }
```

Comment: you need to provide `DocumentSnapshot` on doc

Comment: It's still say error. `The argument type 'Type' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'DocumentSnapshot<Object?>'.`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the model I created before. I hope it is helpful for you.

```dart
class ProductModel {
  static const ID = "id";
  static const IMAGE = "image";
  static const NAME = "name";
  static const BRAND = "brand";
  static const PRICE = "price";

  String? id;
  String? image;
  String? name;
  String? brand;
  int? price;

  ProductModel(
      {required this.id,
        required this.image,
        required this.name,
        required this.brand,
        required this.price});

  factory ProductModel.fromFire(QueryDocumentSnapshot snapshot) {
    return ProductModel.fromMap(snapshot as Map<String, dynamic>);
  }
  factory ProductModel.fromDocumentSnapshot({required DocumentSnapshot<Map<String,dynamic>> doc}){
    // print(doc.data()!["id"]);
    // print(doc.data()!["image"]);
    // print(doc.data()!["name"]);
    // print(doc.data()!["brand"]);
    // print(doc.data()!["price"]);
    return ProductModel(
      id: doc.data()!["id"],
      image: doc.data()!["image"],
      name: doc.data()!["name"],
      brand: doc.data()!["brand"],
      price: doc.data()!["price"],
    );
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    'id': id,
    'image': image,
    'name': name,
    'brand': brand,
    'price': price,
  };

  ProductModel.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> data) {
    id = data[ID];
    image = data[IMAGE];
    name = data[NAME];
    brand = data[BRAND];
    price = data[PRICE];
  }
}
```

Source Code: defining function

```dart
Future<void> getMessagesTestTest() async{

    var aa = await _firestore.collection('ProductModel').snapshots().map((notes){
      notesFromFirestore.clear();
      for(final DocumentSnapshot<Map<String,dynamic>> doc in notes.docs){
        log("start in loop");
        log('doc.id == ${doc.id}');
        // print("start in loop");
        // print('doc.id == ${doc.id}');
        notesFromFirestore.add(ProductModel.fromDocumentSnapshot(doc:doc));
        // print(ProductModel.fromDocumentSnapshot(doc:doc));
      }
      // print(notesFromFirestore.first.id.toString());
      return notesFromFirestore;});
    // int count = await allData.length;
    aa.listen(
          (event) => print("Data Retrieved"),
    );
    // print(aa.length);
    print( 'List Size = ${notesFromFirestore.length}');
    var count = 0;
    for (final ProductModel notesFromFirestoreA in notesFromFirestore) {
      count++;
      print('Loop Counter == ${count}');
      print('Id == ${notesFromFirestoreA.id}');
      print('Name == ${notesFromFirestoreA.name}');
      print('Price == ${notesFromFirestoreA.price}');
      print('Brand == ${notesFromFirestoreA.brand}');
      print('image == ${notesFromFirestoreA.image}');
    }
  }
```